# How to suppress and not to print the backtrace of the exception on the terminal in ruby using Thor?

Tags: ruby, exception, thor

Following is my method that might raise the exception.

Its a method of the CLI too that I am building.

Whenever the exception occurs, I want to catch that and just print my custom message on the terminal.

```
# variation 1
def self.validate(yaml_path)
  begin
    ....
    ....
  rescue
    puts "Error"
  end
end

# variation 2
def self.validate(yaml_path)
  begin
    ....
    ....
  rescue Exceptino => e
    puts "Error: #{e.message}"
  end
end
```

But the backtrace gets printed on the terminal.

How to avoid the backtrace to get printed?

```
± ../../bin/cf site create                                                                                                                                                                          

ruby-1.8.7-p352
Error during processing: syntax error on line 52, col 10: `          - label: Price'
/Users/millisami/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load': syntax error on line 52, col 10: `          - label: Price' (ArgumentError)
.... backtrace .....
.............
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer was to rescue it on the executable file at `bin/<exe>`.
[Thanks for suggesting](https://github.com/wycats/thor/issues/164#issuecomment-1901064)

```
begin
  Cf::CLI.start
rescue Psych::SyntaxError
  $stderr.puts "\n\tError during processing: #{$!.message}\n\n"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code doesn't output the backtrace.

```
class CLS
  def hi
    begin
      raise "X"
    rescue
      puts $!.message
    end
  end
end

CLS.new.hi
```

Have you checked to see if there is another point in the stack where another method is rescuing the exception, outputting the stack trace and then re-raising the exception?

Comment: Though I put `puts $!.message`, the stacktrace is still printing. And I couldn't find any thing that is re-raising the error in my code. But I think since I'm using the `thor` library, it might be the one that is reraising error. Here is the gist https://gist.github.com/1167353 of the full stacktrace. Can you look at it which exception should I rescue, if its due to thor?

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with `thor`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not rescuing the exception is because `Psych::SyntaxError` is not descended from `StandardError`, so a simple `rescue` won't catch it. You need to specify a descendant of `Psych::SyntaxError`:

```
>> require 'psych'
=> true
>> begin; raise Psych::SyntaxError; rescue; puts "GOT IT"; end
# Psych::SyntaxError: Psych::SyntaxError
#   from (irb):8
#   from /Users/donovan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
>> Psych::SyntaxError.ancestors
=> [Psych::SyntaxError, SyntaxError, ScriptError, Exception, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
>> begin; raise Psych::SyntaxError; rescue Exception; puts "GOT IT"; end
GOT IT
```

Notice that in my example `rescue Exception` does catch it. You should generally be as specific as you can when rescuing unless you really *need* to rescue all `Exceptions`. Be aware that suppressing backtraces is good when the exception is something you expect, but if you don't expect it in general it makes debugging much harder.